# how to fix error " Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, content-security-policy

i want using iframe in html but i got this error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'".
> Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-P5polb1UreUSOe5V/Pv7tc+yeZuJXiOi/3fqhGsU7BE='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

my code :

```
<iframe src="test.com" height="200" width="300" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

how can i fix this error
thanks inadvance

Answer (score 3):

Iframe it has nothing to do with it, you have an inline script like `<script>...</script>` in the HTML code. Therefore you have opts:

- to add `'unsafe-inline'` into `script-src` directive (unsafe way)
- to use [`'nonce-value'`](https://csplite.com/csp99/)
- to use [`'hash-value'`](https://csplite.com/csp102/) *'sha256-P5polb1UreUSOe5V/Pv7tc+yeZuJXiOi/3fqhGsU7BE='*
- move inline script to external file, and it will fall under `'self'` token allowance.

Comment: I am running into the same issues as OP.  Could you elaborate on your stated solution.  In my Cordova app, my directive is in my HTML head as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready data: myApp:; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`.    The source for the iFrame is `https://docs.google.com/gview=example.com/somefile.pdf&embedded=true`