# Microsoft Add-In manifest doesn't work on outlook web

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have developed a microsoft office add-in for outlook that can be seen here https://cdnqa.mcfile.com/mcoffice/manifest.outlook.xml

I have tested and it works as expected on local and production environment. I have validated the XMLs with the tool `office-addin-manifest validate`

That yields a positive result for multiple platforms, including web:

```
Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:

  - Outlook 2013 or later on Windows

  - Outlook 2016 or later on Windows

  - Outlook 2019 or later on Windows

  - Outlook 2013 or later on Mac

  - Outlook 2016 or later on Mac

  - Outlook 2019 or later on Mac

  - Outlook on the web

  - Outlook on Windows (Microsoft 365)

  - Outlook on Mac (Microsoft 365)

Important: This analysis is based on the requirements specified in your manifest and does not account for any runtime JavaScript calls within your add-in. For information 

about which API sets and features are supported on each platform, see Office Add-in host and platform availability. (https://docs.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability).

*This does not include mobile apps. You can opt-in to support mobile apps when you submit your add-in.

The manifest is valid.
```

But when trying to open the taskpane on outlook web I'm faced with the following error:

[image: screenshot of panel with an red cross sign and text that says: "add-in error Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator."]

Note that this error do not exists on the desktop version. I can use the app normally on all other versions except web and web based like the new outlook desktop. Do anyone had a similar issue and know the cause or how to troubleshoot web add-ins?

Comment: Could you try to use developer tools (F12) of the browser and see if there will be an error message in the console output?

Comment: Does the page your opening contain a reference to `office.js` and an `office.initialize` method?

Comment: When you get that error, paste the URL in the `<SourceLocation>` element of your manifest into an ordinary browser window and see if the page opens.

Comment: We can repro the issue and in console, we see the error which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788612/how-to-fix-error-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-it-violates-the-foll). Can you please try out the solution mentioned in the other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788612/how-to-fix-error-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-it-violates-the-foll)?

Comment: no @EugeneAstafiev, is this required? didn't see it on the documentation

Comment: it opens normally @RickKirkham

Comment: Try to add things mentioned in my previous post and let me know whether it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603351/eugene-astafiev), importing office.js and implementing an office.initialize call enabled the app to load.